# Monitoring CPU load, System Performance and Zombie using Nagios

Tags: linux, operating-system, rhel, nagios

I have recently installed nagios to monitor few remote systems... the remote system latency is as below..

`icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=254 ms`

I have configured nagios to monitor the CPU load, Total Processes and Zombie process. It does send me an email for all the system hikes.. however in the additional info it specifies this message

```
(Return code of 255 is out of bounds)
```

Since this is just an additional message, can i ignore this and trust Nagios on its notification ?

or is it because of the latency between the Nagios server and the monitored machine the Nagios could not appropriately get the information ?

Comment: Do i need to install NPRE client as well on the monitored machine ?

Comment: You only need the NRPE *server* on the monitored machine.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the checks are failing.

You don't say what mechanism you're using to get information from the remote host (SNMP, NRPE or what have you), so I can't be more specific, but looking in Nagios's log file should give you more of a clue as to what's going wrong (defined by `log_file` in your Nagios config; on my system it's `/var/log/nagios3/nagios.log`).

Comment: thank you for the response... we are using nrpe... in the log i see the below messages.

[1403085651] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'CPU Load' on host 'XX' was out of bounds.
[1403085800] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'Total Processes' on host 'XXX' was out of bounds.
[1403085949] Warning: Return code of 255 for check of service 'Zombie Processes' on host 'XXX' was out of bounds..

Comment: Can you add some config to your question -- the stanzas defining the services and commands would be very helpful.

Comment: Below is the service


#define service{
#        use                             generic-service
#        host_name                       XXXXX
#        service_description             Zombie Processes
#        contact_groups                  YYYYYYYY
#        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_zombie_procs
#        }